# OverflowError in Python Jupyter Using pd.read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am running a SQL query in Python.  I believe the engine has been created as it prints: `"Engine(postgresql://username:***address:5432/DBNAME)"`

The code I am running is:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE year > 2018', engine)
```

I am expecting a dataframe with two columns.  Instead I receive an error stating:

> OverflowError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>   OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

I checked

```
import sys
sys.maxsize
```

Out: `9223372036854775807`